# Postgresql doesn't respond, select * from claims where case_number='22222' but responds select * from claims

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql doesn't respond,  select * from claims where case_number='22222' but responds select * from claims I don't understand the reason who can help please

I have restarted postgresql and normally works 5-10 minutes
postgresql version 12

Comment: What is the data type of case_number? Are you certain that case number 22222 exists? What if you try a different one, do you get results then?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't respond"? Zero results or it is taking a long time to answer? How many records are there, is there an index on case_number?

Comment: Perhaps `claims` is a view, not a table?

Comment: it is taking a lot of time, 947051 records

Comment: I'm looking for existing case numbers but it takes lot of time to respond almost not respond, all case numbers same situation I think postgresql blocking something because other queries working normally

Comment: try to (re)index the field

Comment: Without, at the  minimum, the output of  `EXPLAIN <the_query>` I don't see this getting a useful answer. Post the results as text update to your question.

Comment: Another possibility. You are retrieving approximately 1M rows. You probably should  also investigate network latency and the time your app takes to format the result.